Using 3d printer fabricated gears or pipes and having a machine apply force upwards, how can I move a lever sideways?
I have one of those electric jacks. I can apply up to 3000lb of force in up direction. I have a series of pipes that attach to a socket that turns a nut east or west, but my machine only applies a force north. How can I fashion a set of pipes that attach to the end of the socket and to the jack or using gears that I could fabricate from a 3d printer or lets say a chain and sprocket from a bicycle, how can I turn this nut left or right?

3000 lb of force and 3D printer are not terms that would normally go together. Can you [edit] to improve your question: 1. What have pipes got to do with turning a nut? 2. Clockwise / anti-clockwise are the terms for rotational direction. If a nut turns "east or west" then it's also turning "north or south". 3. How much torque is required? 4. What size nut? 5. Are there space constraints? 6. Can you provide a photo of the equipment? Welcome to E.SE!
